# Explanation on the non existence of this limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x^2 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Does the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exist?

I require some explanation in the procedure. I mean, if I take two sequences $a_n = -x^2 + \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = 1 + \frac{\pi}{n}$, then for $n\to +\infty$ they do converge to $-x^2$ and to $1$. So far so good.

But I am missing the reason the limit doesn't exist. What do those sequences tell me?

Comment: Why does $a_n$ depend on $x$?

Comment: If $x$ goes to $+\infty$ then you have 2 subsequences: $a_n=n$, $f(a_n) = -n^2\to -\infty$ and $b_n = n\pi$, $f(b_n) = 1 \to 1$

Comment: @EgorIvanov Well I thought that I had to find a sequence converging to $-x^2$...

Comment: How can anything converge to $-x^2$ if $x$ is not a defined constant?  But even if what you said make sense, $-x^2$ and $1$ are not the same thing.  So didn't you just argue that the limit can't exist?  If a limit exists it has to be one thing.  It can't be *both* $-x^2$ (which is not a number) *AND* $1$.

Comment: The idea is that $a_n$ is any sequences of only rational values.  THe simplest and most obvious one would be $a_n = n$ but it doesn't matter.  Any $a_n$ so that $a_n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ will work.  And $b_n$ is any sequence of irrational values so that $b_n\to\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.  $b_n = n + \pi$ is a simple one but any will do.  Then $f(a_n)= a_n^2 \to \infty$.  While $f(b_n) = 1\to 1$.  That's all.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you!! Is there a theorem or some motivation for which I can be sure that EVERY sequence work?

Comment: " Well I thought that I had to find a sequence converging to $−x^n$..."   I don't know where you got that idea but it is simply wrong and doesn't actually make sense.  I think you misinterpreted something.

Comment: "Is there a theorem or some motivation for which I can be sure that EVERY sequence work?" .  Not really.   If $a_n$ is a sequence so that a) $a_k \in \mathbb Q$ and b) $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =\infty $ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n^2 \to \infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^2 = \infty$.  While if $b_n$ is a sequence so that a) $a_k \not \in \mathbb Q$ and b) $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = \infty$ the $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(b_k) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively $f$ goes to minus infinity on the rationals and to $1$ on the irrationals therefore it cannot have a limit since it has multiple adherence values.

So just take $x_{2n}$ a rational sequence going to infinity e.g. $x_{2n}=n$ and take $x_{2n+1}$ an irrational one e.g. $x_{2n+1}=n\pi$.

Then $\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_{2n})=-\infty\\\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_{2n+1})=1\end{cases}$

The $x$ appears both in $f(x)$ and in $-x^2$, so it is the variable not a constant. This is the reason why I wrote my sequence $x_n$ to show it is a variable $x$ that goes to infinity when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Ahhh, now I got my error! Well that is really clear, thank you!!